# Compiles as C++ but not C (error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand)

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, lvalue, rvalue

This line compiles when I use C++, but not C:

`gmtime(&(*(time_t *)alloca(sizeof(time_t)) = time(NULL))); //make an lvalue with alloca`

I'm surprised by this difference. There is not even a warning for C++.

When I specify `gcc -x c`, the message is:

```
playground.cpp:25:8: error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand
 gmtime(&(*(time_t *)alloca(sizeof(time_t)) = time(NULL)));
        ^
```

Isn't the `&` here just an address-of operator? Why is it different in C and C++?

Although I can use compound literals in C, still is it possible to modify my syntax to make it work in both C & C++?

Comment: Also the difference isn't about `&`, it seems to be about whether `(*(time_t *)alloca(sizeof(time_t)) = time(NULL))` is an lvalue or not.

Comment: Also, why not just write this on two lines? `time_t t = time(NULL); gmtime(&t);`

Comment: @immibis mainly because I want to get an address of a temporary object (the `time_t` value is used only once). I found compound literals in C so convenient but I cannot use it in C++.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C11 6.5.16/3:

> An assignment operator stores a value in the object designated by the left operand. An assignment expression has the value of the left operand after the assignment, **but is not an lvalue**.

In C++14 5.17/1:

> The assignment operator (=) and the compound assignment operators all group right-to-left. All require a modifiable lvalue as their left operand **and return an lvalue** referring to the left operand.

(Earlier versions of the language standards in each case specified the same thing).

Since the address-of operator can only operate on an lvalue, the code is correct in C++ but not in C.

---

Regarding the question "Is it possible to modify my syntax to make it work in both C & C++?".  This is not a desirable goal; the two languages are different and you should decide what you're writing. This makes about as much sense as trying to stick to syntax that works in both C and Java.

As suggested by others, you could write:

```
time_t t = time(NULL);
gmtime(&t);
```

which has the benefits over your original code of being:

- simpler, therefore easier to understand and maintain
- does not depend on non-standard `alloca` function
- does not have potential alignment violation
- uses no more memory and perhaps uses less

Comment: I don't know the rationale behind the rule, but I'd figure that originally in C it was never an lvalue (there's rarely any cause to try and modify the result of an assignment), but when C++ was being developed, they changed it to be an lvalue for consistency with objects that overload `operator=` and return a reference to self (which is an lvalue).

Comment: Nice job. I knew it had to do with different rules concerning rvalues and lvalues but I was looking into the `&` operator and not the `=` operator. +1.